# Permutation of a 2D array

Tags: java, permutation

Here comes another question about permutations. I have done everything I can to formulate my problem as good as I possibly can. Feel free to ask questions if there is something you do not understand.

I have a list, containing a list, containing a list, containing a symbol.

```
List<List<List<Symbol>>> list = new ArrayList<List<List<Symbol>>>();
```

The symbol class simply takes on a value and keeps track of some important features of what I am creating. All the symbols in the structure are different from one another.

There are however some difficulties as to just switching places in all different ways, since...

**The first list** is a sort of wrapper for the whole thing. It contains groupings of two lists containing symbols. This is because the symbols are not supposed to be seperate from one another when contained in a grouping.

**The second list** is always of length two, and each contains a list of unique symbols. As to why it is two, do not ask me for this question. It would be nice for this program to have the capability to also be able to deal with this list being greater than two in length.

**The third list** contains all the symbols, and there are two of those per wrapper, as stated above.

What I want with this is to generate all possible permutations and analyze them. That is, I would like the symbols to switch into all possible combination whilst still being contained within its respective list.

This could look something like this (written in pseudo-code, depicting the list-like structure mentioned above).

```
[[a, b, c], [d, e, f]],
[[g, h, i, j], [k, l, m, n]],
[[o, p], [q, r]],
[[s, t, u], [v, x, y]],
```

An example for what one of the (possibly thousands) of permutations could be, is this.

```
[[c, a, b], [d, f, e]],
[[g, h, j, i], [k, l, m, n]],
[[o, p], [q, r]],
[[s, t, u], [v,y, x]],
```

**What I have tried so far** is to put these into a good old traditional permutations method that works for a single array (or list, if you will), and tried to modify that into working with multidimensional arrays. Surely there is a good and simple way to do this, preferably with the use of recursion. Should there be a way without, that is totally okay.

Once again, if you have any questions above what I just wrote, feel free to post a comment.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution. `permutationsList` can take lists with an arbitrary number of dimensions. Btw. the example you gave has nearly 3 million permutations. My program takes several seconds to calculate all of them.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Perm {
  static <T> List<List<T>> permutations(List<T> list) {
    if(list.isEmpty()) return new LinkedList<>();
    List<List<T>> result = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      T elem = list.get(i);
      List<T> copy = new LinkedList<>(list);
      copy.remove(i);
      List<List<T>> permRest = permutations(copy);
      if(permRest.isEmpty()) permRest.add(new LinkedList<>());
      for(List<T> perm: permRest) {
        List<T> permCopy = new LinkedList<>(perm);
        permCopy.add(0, elem);
        result.add(permCopy);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  static List<List> permutationsLists(List list) {
    if(list.size() == 0) {
      return new LinkedList<>();
    } if(!(list.get(0) instanceof List)) {
      return permutations(list);
    } else {
      List<List> permutationsFirst = permutationsLists((List)list.get(0));
      List<List> permutationsRest = (List<List>)permutationsLists(list.subList(1, list.size()));
      if(permutationsRest.size() == 0) permutationsRest.add(new LinkedList());
      List<List> result = new LinkedList<>();
      for(List pf: permutationsFirst) {
        for(List pr: permutationsRest) {
          List copy = new LinkedList(pr);
          copy.add(0, pf);
          result.add(copy);
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
    List<List<List<String>>> list = Arrays.asList(
      Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"), Arrays.asList("d", "e", "f")),
      Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("g", "h", "i", "j"), Arrays.asList("k", "l", "m", "n")),
      Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("o", "p"), Arrays.asList("q", "r")),
      Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("s", "t", "u"), Arrays.asList("v", "w", "x"))
    );
    */
    List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3), Arrays.asList(4,5));
    System.out.println(permutationsLists(list));
  }
}
```

edit:
Here is a solution using streams. It's very efficient and can generate a huge number of permutations without using up much ram. btw you can convert a stream to an iterator with the `iterator()` method.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Perm {

  static <T> Stream<List<T>> permutations(List<T> list) {
    if(list.isEmpty()) return Stream.empty();
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size()).boxed().flatMap(i -> {
      T elem = list.get(i);
      List<T> copy = new LinkedList<>(list);
      copy.remove((int)i);
      Stream<List<T>> permRest = copy.isEmpty()?Stream.of(new LinkedList<>()):permutations(copy);
      return permRest.map(perm -> {
        List<T> permCopy = new LinkedList<>(perm);
        permCopy.add(0, elem);
        return permCopy;
      });
    });
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  static <T> Stream<List<T>> permutationsLists(List<T> list) {
    if(list.size() == 0) {
      return Stream.empty();
    } if(!(list.get(0) instanceof List)) {
      return permutations(list);
    } else {
      List rawList = list;
      Stream<List> permutationsFirst = permutationsLists((List)list.get(0));

      return permutationsFirst.flatMap(pf -> {
        Stream<List> permutationsRest = list.size() < 2?Stream.of(new LinkedList()):permutationsLists(rawList.subList(1, list.size()));
        return permutationsRest.map(pr -> {
          List<T> copy = new LinkedList<>(pr);
          copy.add(0, (T)pf);
          return copy;
        });
      });
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<List<List<String>>> list = Arrays.asList(
      Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"), Arrays.asList("d", "e", "f")),
      Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("g", "h", "i", "j"), Arrays.asList("k", "l", "m", "n")),
      Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("o", "p"), Arrays.asList("q", "r")),
      Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("s", "t", "u"), Arrays.asList("v", "w", "x"))
    );

    Stream<List<List<List<String>>>> result = permutationsLists(list);
    result.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p));
  }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this technically is a correct answer, it runs out of memory for me after being at it for quite some time. I will mark your answer as correct, however, I would love if you had any suggestions as to how I would go about analyzing all these three million possible combinations.

Comment: You can increase the amount of available ram e.g. to 1GB with `java -Xmx1G Perm` But i suppose a better solution would be to not put all 3 million permutations in ram but instead have `permutationsLists` return an iterator.

Comment: I have not used iterators in Java before, I am assuming you are talking about the iterator class. Would you be so kind to show me any means towards implementing one?

Comment: I noticed that the Stream class has all the functionality built in to do what I had in mind. So I added a solution using that.

Comment: Thank you, so very much. Your help means a great deal to me. I upvoted your answer, and I am assuming the count() tells you how many permutations there are - actually, I could probably check that out myself. Once again, thank you!

Comment: Glad you like my solution. I changed my code some more and converted the `permutations` method to use streams as well.